# how can list row with max value of one column

Tags: oracle

I have some database like example below.

```
WITH TB AS(
     SELECT 'A' C1, 'B' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 1 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A' C1, 'B' AS C2, 2 AS N1, 2 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 3 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 2 AS N1, 4 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 3 AS N1, 1 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'A2' C1, 'B2' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 6 AS N2 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB
```

How can I list all row with Max(N1), and group by C1, C2 like Image below?

[image]

Comment: Max(n1) = 3, so why so why are the records from N1 <> 3 in your example? These requirements are unclear.

Comment: I want get all row with group by C1, C2, and Max N1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the requirements in the question is unclear, I am guesing that max(n1) should be calculated **for each group of C1+c2**.
If this is a case, then you can use `MAX() OVER ()` analytic function in this way:

```
SELECT tb.*,
       max( n1 ) over (partition by c1, c2 ) xxxx
FROM TB;

| C1 | C2 | N1 | N2 | XXXX |
|----|----|----|----|------|
|  A |  B |  1 |  1 |    2 |
|  A |  B |  2 |  2 |    2 |
| A1 | B1 |  1 |  3 |    3 |
| A1 | B1 |  2 |  4 |    3 |
| A1 | B1 |  3 |  1 |    3 |
| A2 | B2 |  1 |  6 |    1 |
```

and then wrap the above query as a subquery, and filter out unwanted rows:

```
SELECT c1,c2,n1,n2 FROM (
  SELECT tb.*,
       max( n1 ) over (partition by c1, c2 ) xxxx
  FROM TB
)
WHERE n1 = xxxx

| C1 | C2 | N1 | N2 |
|----|----|----|----|
|  A |  B |  2 |  2 |
| A1 | B1 |  3 |  1 |
| A2 | B2 |  1 |  6 |
```

---

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2fb9/4

Answer (score 2):

One way is using `KEEP .. DENSE_RANK`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/500)

**Query 1**:

```
    WITH TB AS(
         SELECT 'A' C1, 'B' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 1 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A' C1, 'B' AS C2, 2 AS N1, 2 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 3 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 2 AS N1, 4 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A1' C1, 'B1' AS C2, 3 AS N1, 1 AS N2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A2' C1, 'B2' AS C2, 1 AS N1, 6 AS N2 FROM DUAL 
    )
   SELECT C1
    ,C2
    ,MAX(N1) AS N1
    ,MAX(N2) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY N1 DESC
        ) AS N2
FROM TB
GROUP BY C1
    ,C2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/500/0)**:

```
| C1 | C2 | N1 | N2 |
|----|----|----|----|
|  A |  B |  2 |  2 |
| A1 | B1 |  3 |  1 |
| A2 | B2 |  1 |  6 |
```